# ActiveMQ Artemis logging format as JSON

Tags: json, activemq-artemis, jboss-logging

I'm using ActiveMQ Artemis 2.20.0, and I require logs in JSON format.

I tried to use a JSON formatter in the `logging.properties` file but I get an error

The following is the change I made to logging.properties

```
# File handler configuration
handler.FILE=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler
handler.FILE.level=DEBUG
handler.FILE.properties=suffix,append,autoFlush,fileName
handler.FILE.suffix=.yyyy-MM-dd
handler.FILE.append=true
handler.FILE.autoFlush=true
handler.FILE.fileName=${artemis.instance}/log/artemis.log
handler.FILE.formatter=JSON

# Formatter pattern configuration
#formatter.PATTERN=org.jboss.logmanager.formatters.PatternFormatter
#formatter.PATTERN.properties=pattern
#formatter.PATTERN.pattern=%d %-5p [%c] %s%E%n

formatter.JSON=org.jboss.logmanager.formatters.JsonFormatter
formatter.JSON.properties=keyOverrides,metaData,prettyPrint,printDetails
formatter.JSON.constructorProperties=keyOverrides
formatter.JSON.keyOverrides=timestamp\=log_timestamp,level\=severity
formatter.JSON.metaData=@version\=1,service_id\=eric-eo-cm-cust-wf,json-format\=true
formatter.JSON.prettyPrint=false
formatter.JSON.printDetails=false
```

The stack trace of error is as follows:

```
No property "keyOverrides" type could be determined for formatter "JSON"Failed to read or configure the org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to instantiate class "org.jboss.logmanager.formatters.JsonFormatter" for formatter "JSON"
        at org.jboss.logmanager.config.AbstractPropertyConfiguration$ConstructAction.validate(AbstractPropertyConfiguration.java:117)
        at org.jboss.logmanager.config.LogContextConfigurationImpl.doPrepare(LogContextConfigurationImpl.java:336)
        at org.jboss.logmanager.config.LogContextConfigurationImpl.prepare(LogContextConfigurationImpl.java:289)
        at org.jboss.logmanager.config.LogContextConfigurationImpl.commit(LogContextConfigurationImpl.java:298)
        at org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:546)
        at org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:97)
        at org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager.readConfiguration(LogManager.java:170)
        at org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager.readConfiguration(LogManager.java:132)
        at java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(LogManager.java:445)
        at java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:394)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager.ensureLogManagerInitialized(LogManager.java:382)
        at java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:430)
        at java.logging/java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:648)
        at java.logging/java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:717)
        at java.logging/java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:701)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.boot.Artemis.<clinit>(Artemis.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at org.jboss.logmanager.config.AbstractPropertyConfiguration$ConstructAction.validate(AbstractPropertyConfiguration.java:115)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/json/Json
        at org.jboss.logmanager.formatters.JsonFormatter.<init>(JsonFormatter.java:76)
        ... 21 more
```

Does the ActiveMQ Artemis logging back-end have a JSON dependency to allow logs to format as JSON?

Comment: Hi Justin - I added the relevant part of logging.properties ..

Comment: Hi Justin - I added more detail - It looks like the backend has no Json formatter

Comment: apache activemq-artemis 2.20

Comment: Justin - which logging framework is artemis using ?

Comment: ActiveMQ Artemis uses JBoss Logging as noted in [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/logging.html).

Comment: I think JBoss Logging is an abstract..there will be a framework behind this

Comment: JBoss Logging is not an abstract. It's a full log manager and logging implementation. Why do you think it is an abstract?

Comment: Reference https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/logging.html

Comment: From what I can tell "JBoss Logging" is the umbrella for both the logging framework (mentioned by the Weld documentation) _and_ the log manager. See [here](https://github.com/jboss-logging). In any case, ActiveMQ Artemis uses **both** the logging framework and log manager from JBoss Logging.

Comment: For what it's worth, the problem here isn't JBoss Logging. It's the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/json/Json` which means the JVM doesn't have the right jar(s) on the classpath.

Comment: Looking at the Github repo JBoss-logging can support all the frameworks (log4j , logback etc..)

Comment: Of course the logging abstraction _can_ support multiple different managers, but ActiveMQ Artemis uses the [JBoss Log Manager](https://github.com/jboss-logging/jboss-logmanager) which is why you configure `logging.properties` with things like `org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler` and `org.jboss.logmanager.formatters.JsonFormatter`.

Comment: *Any* log manager that outputs JSON is likely to use `javax.json.Json` which means they would have the same classloading issue that the JBoss Log Manager is having in this case.

Comment: If no JSon library (like JACKSON) has been used in the backend then it will not matter about the framework ...maybe that explains why the classpath cannot find the jar files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ugly, but you need to:

1. Download [javax.json-1.1.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/javax.json/1.1/javax.json-1.1.jar). This is compatible with [what JBoss Log Manager uses](https://github.com/jboss-logging/jboss-logmanager/blob/2.1.10.Final/pom.xml#L51).
2. Put `javax.json-1.1.jar` in to the `lib` directory of your Artemis' *home* directory (i.e. where you uncompressed the Artemis archive).
3. Modify the `bin/artemis` script from the *instance* to include `javax.json-1.1.jar` in the `-Xbootclasspath`. There is already a line which includes a few jars (including the JBoss Log Manager) which you can modify, e.g.:

   ```
   exec "$JAVACMD" \
       $JAVA_ARGS \
       -Dhawtio.role="$HAWTIO_ROLE" \
       -Xbootclasspath/a:"$LOG_MANAGER:$WILDFLY_COMMON:$ARTEMIS_HOME/lib/javax.json-1.1.jar" \
       -Djava.security.auth.login.config="$ARTEMIS_INSTANCE_ETC/login.config" \
       $ARTEMIS_CLUSTER_PROPS \
       -classpath "$CLASSPATH" \
       -Dartemis.home="$ARTEMIS_HOME" \
       -Dartemis.instance="$ARTEMIS_INSTANCE" \
       -Djava.library.path="$ARTEMIS_HOME/bin/lib/linux-$(uname -m)" \
       -Djava.io.tmpdir="$ARTEMIS_INSTANCE/tmp" \
       -Ddata.dir="$ARTEMIS_DATA_DIR" \
       -Dartemis.instance.etc="$ARTEMIS_INSTANCE_ETC" \
       -Djava.util.logging.manager="$ARTEMIS_LOG_MANAGER" \
       -Dlogging.configuration="$ARTEMIS_LOGGING_CONF" \
       -Dartemis.default.sensitive.string.codec.key="$ARTEMIS_DEFAULT_SENSITIVE_STRING_CODEC_KEY" \
       $DEBUG_ARGS \
       org.apache.activemq.artemis.boot.Artemis "$@"
   ```

This is complicated because of the mess caused by Oracle not allowing Eclipse to use the `javax` namespace when Oracle donated Java EE to them. Everything named `javax` had to be *renamed* to `jakarta` for Jakarta EE 9 which has [a lot of consequences](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2020/november/1.php). Since ActiveMQ Artemis can be embedded into both Java EE **and** Jarkata EE environments we need to be able to work no matter what JSON API is provided. Therefore, we wrapped the `javax.json` API with our own and then shaded both the API and the Apache Johnzon implementation into our distribution. See [ARTEMIS-3546](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-3546) for more details on that.

The problem with wrapping & shading is that external libraries like JBoss Logging Log Manager which might need `javax.json` don't have it which is why you need to add it manually. Hopefully this will be sorted out better in a future version of ActiveMQ Artemis.

Here's what the JSON looking looks like:

```
$ ./artemis run
     _        _               _
    / \  ____| |_  ___ __  __(_) _____
   / _ \|  _ \ __|/ _ \  \/  | |/  __/
  / ___ \ | \/ |_/  __/ |\/| | |\___ \
 /_/   \_\|   \__\____|_|  |_|_|/___ /
 Apache ActiveMQ Artemis 2.20.0


{"log_timestamp":"2022-03-10T13:38:27.241-06:00","sequence":0,"loggerClassName":"java.util.logging.Logger","loggerName":"org.apache.activemq.artemis.integration.bootstrap","severity":"INFO","message":"AMQ101000: Starting ActiveMQ Artemis Server","threadName":"main","threadId":1,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"workhorse","processName":"Artemis","processId":1025544,"@version":"1","service_id":"eric-eo-cm-cust-wf","json-format":"true"}
{"log_timestamp":"2022-03-10T13:38:27.267-06:00","sequence":2,"loggerClassName":"java.util.logging.Logger","loggerName":"org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server","severity":"INFO","message":"AMQ221000: live Message Broker is starting with configuration Broker Configuration (clustered=false,journalDirectory=data/journal,bindingsDirectory=data/bindings,largeMessagesDirectory=data/large-messages,pagingDirectory=data/paging)","threadName":"main","threadId":1,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"workhorse","processName":"Artemis","processId":1025544,"@version":"1","service_id":"eric-eo-cm-cust-wf","json-format":"true"}
{"log_timestamp":"2022-03-10T13:38:27.289-06:00","sequence":4,"loggerClassName":"java.util.logging.Logger","loggerName":"org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server","severity":"INFO","message":"AMQ221012: Using AIO Journal","threadName":"main","threadId":1,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"workhorse","processName":"Artemis","processId":1025544,"@version":"1","service_id":"eric-eo-cm-cust-wf","json-format":"true"}
{"log_timestamp":"2022-03-10T13:38:27.324-06:00","sequence":6,"loggerClassName":"java.util.logging.Logger","loggerName":"org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server","severity":"INFO","message":"AMQ221057: Global Max Size is being adjusted to 1/2 of the JVM max size (-Xmx). being defined as 1,073,741,824","threadName":"main","threadId":1,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"workhorse","processName":"Artemis","processId":1025544,"@version":"1","service_id":"eric-eo-cm-cust-wf","json-format":"true"}
{"log_timestamp":"2022-03-10T13:38:27.34-06:00","sequence":8,"loggerClassName":"java.util.logging.Logger","loggerName":"org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server","severity":"INFO","message":"AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-server]. Adding protocol support for: CORE","threadName":"main","threadId":1,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"workhorse","processName":"Artemis","processId":1025544,"@version":"1","service_id":"eric-eo-cm-cust-wf","json-format":"true"}
{"log_timestamp":"2022-03-10T13:38:27.341-06:00","sequence":10,"loggerClassName":"java.util.logging.Logger","loggerName":"org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server","severity":"INFO","message":"AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-amqp-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: AMQP","threadName":"main","threadId":1,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"workhorse","processName":"Artemis","processId":1025544,"@version":"1","service_id":"eric-eo-cm-cust-wf","json-format":"true"}
{"log_timestamp":"2022-03-10T13:38:27.342-06:00","sequence":12,"loggerClassName":"java.util.logging.Logger","loggerName":"org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server","severity":"INFO","message":"AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-hornetq-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: HORNETQ","threadName":"main","threadId":1,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"workhorse","processName":"Artemis","processId":1025544,"@version":"1","service_id":"eric-eo-cm-cust-wf","json-format":"true"}
{"log_timestamp":"2022-03-10T13:38:27.342-06:00","sequence":14,"loggerClassName":"java.util.logging.Logger","loggerName":"org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server","severity":"INFO","message":"AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-mqtt-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: MQTT","threadName":"main","threadId":1,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"workhorse","processName":"Artemis","processId":1025544,"@version":"1","service_id":"eric-eo-cm-cust-wf","json-format":"true"}
{"log_timestamp":"2022-03-10T13:38:27.343-06:00","sequence":16,"loggerClassName":"java.util.logging.Logger","loggerName":"org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server","severity":"INFO","message":"AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-openwire-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: OPENWIRE","threadName":"main","threadId":1,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"workhorse","processName":"Artemis","processId":1025544,"@version":"1","service_id":"eric-eo-cm-cust-wf","json-format":"true"}
{"log_timestamp":"2022-03-10T13:38:27.343-06:00","sequence":18,"loggerClassName":"java.util.logging.Logger","loggerName":"org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server","severity":"INFO","message":"AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-stomp-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: STOMP","threadName":"main","threadId":1,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"workhorse","processName":"Artemis","processId":1025544,"@version":"1","service_id":"eric-eo-cm-cust-wf","json-format":"true"}
{"log_timestamp":"2022-03-10T13:38:27.396-06:00","sequence":20,"loggerClassName":"java.util.logging.Logger","loggerName":"org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server","severity":"INFO","message":"AMQ221034: Waiting indefinitely to obtain live lock","threadName":"main","threadId":1,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"workhorse","processName":"Artemis","processId":1025544,"@version":"1","service_id":"eric-eo-cm-cust-wf","json-format":"true"}
{"log_timestamp":"2022-03-10T13:38:27.397-06:00","sequence":22,"loggerClassName":"java.util.logging.Logger","loggerName":"org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server","severity":"INFO","message":"AMQ221035: Live Server Obtained live lock","threadName":"main","threadId":1,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"workhorse","processName":"Artemis","processId":1025544,"@version":"1","service_id":"eric-eo-cm-cust-wf","json-format":"true"}
{"log_timestamp":"2022-03-10T13:38:27.574-06:00","sequence":24,"loggerClassName":"java.util.logging.Logger","loggerName":"org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server","severity":"INFO","message":"AMQ221080: Deploying address DLQ supporting [ANYCAST]","threadName":"main","threadId":1,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"workhorse","processName":"Artemis","processId":1025544,"@version":"1","service_id":"eric-eo-cm-cust-wf","json-format":"true"}
{"log_timestamp":"2022-03-10T13:38:27.576-06:00","sequence":26,"loggerClassName":"java.util.logging.Logger","loggerName":"org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server","severity":"INFO","message":"AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue DLQ on address DLQ","threadName":"main","threadId":1,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"workhorse","processName":"Artemis","processId":1025544,"@version":"1","service_id":"eric-eo-cm-cust-wf","json-format":"true"}
{"log_timestamp":"2022-03-10T13:38:27.581-06:00","sequence":28,"loggerClassName":"java.util.logging.Logger","loggerName":"org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server","severity":"INFO","message":"AMQ221080: Deploying address ExpiryQueue supporting [ANYCAST]","threadName":"main","threadId":1,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"workhorse","processName":"Artemis","processId":1025544,"@version":"1","service_id":"eric-eo-cm-cust-wf","json-format":"true"}
{"log_timestamp":"2022-03-10T13:38:27.582-06:00","sequence":30,"loggerClassName":"java.util.logging.Logger","loggerName":"org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server","severity":"INFO","message":"AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue ExpiryQueue on address ExpiryQueue","threadName":"main","threadId":1,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"workhorse","processName":"Artemis","processId":1025544,"@version":"1","service_id":"eric-eo-cm-cust-wf","json-format":"true"}
{"log_timestamp":"2022-03-10T13:38:27.85-06:00","sequence":32,"loggerClassName":"java.util.logging.Logger","loggerName":"org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server","severity":"INFO","message":"AMQ221020: Started NIO Acceptor at 0.0.0.0:61616 for protocols [CORE,MQTT,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,OPENWIRE]","threadName":"main","threadId":1,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"workhorse","processName":"Artemis","processId":1025544,"@version":"1","service_id":"eric-eo-cm-cust-wf","json-format":"true"}
{"log_timestamp":"2022-03-10T13:38:27.874-06:00","sequence":34,"loggerClassName":"java.util.logging.Logger","loggerName":"org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server","severity":"INFO","message":"AMQ221020: Started NIO Acceptor at 0.0.0.0:5445 for protocols [HORNETQ,STOMP]","threadName":"main","threadId":1,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"workhorse","processName":"Artemis","processId":1025544,"@version":"1","service_id":"eric-eo-cm-cust-wf","json-format":"true"}
{"log_timestamp":"2022-03-10T13:38:27.878-06:00","sequence":36,"loggerClassName":"java.util.logging.Logger","loggerName":"org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server","severity":"INFO","message":"AMQ221020: Started NIO Acceptor at 0.0.0.0:5672 for protocols [AMQP]","threadName":"main","threadId":1,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"workhorse","processName":"Artemis","processId":1025544,"@version":"1","service_id":"eric-eo-cm-cust-wf","json-format":"true"}
{"log_timestamp":"2022-03-10T13:38:27.909-06:00","sequence":38,"loggerClassName":"java.util.logging.Logger","loggerName":"org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server","severity":"INFO","message":"AMQ221020: Started NIO Acceptor at 0.0.0.0:1883 for protocols [MQTT]","threadName":"main","threadId":1,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"workhorse","processName":"Artemis","processId":1025544,"@version":"1","service_id":"eric-eo-cm-cust-wf","json-format":"true"}
{"log_timestamp":"2022-03-10T13:38:27.914-06:00","sequence":40,"loggerClassName":"java.util.logging.Logger","loggerName":"org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server","severity":"INFO","message":"AMQ221020: Started NIO Acceptor at 0.0.0.0:61613 for protocols [STOMP]","threadName":"main","threadId":1,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"workhorse","processName":"Artemis","processId":1025544,"@version":"1","service_id":"eric-eo-cm-cust-wf","json-format":"true"}
{"log_timestamp":"2022-03-10T13:38:27.916-06:00","sequence":42,"loggerClassName":"java.util.logging.Logger","loggerName":"org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server","severity":"INFO","message":"AMQ221007: Server is now live","threadName":"main","threadId":1,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"workhorse","processName":"Artemis","processId":1025544,"@version":"1","service_id":"eric-eo-cm-cust-wf","json-format":"true"}
{"log_timestamp":"2022-03-10T13:38:27.917-06:00","sequence":44,"loggerClassName":"java.util.logging.Logger","loggerName":"org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server","severity":"INFO","message":"AMQ221001: Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Message Broker version 2.20.0 [0.0.0.0, nodeID=f41aef33-a07b-11ec-aa6f-5c80b6f32172] ","threadName":"main","threadId":1,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"workhorse","processName":"Artemis","processId":1025544,"@version":"1","service_id":"eric-eo-cm-cust-wf","json-format":"true"}
{"log_timestamp":"2022-03-10T13:38:28.1-06:00","sequence":46,"loggerClassName":"org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLogger","loggerName":"org.apache.activemq.hawtio.branding.PluginContextListener","severity":"INFO","message":"Initialized activemq-branding plugin","threadName":"main","threadId":1,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"workhorse","processName":"Artemis","processId":1025544,"@version":"1","service_id":"eric-eo-cm-cust-wf","json-format":"true"}
{"log_timestamp":"2022-03-10T13:38:28.124-06:00","sequence":47,"loggerClassName":"org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLogger","loggerName":"org.apache.activemq.hawtio.plugin.PluginContextListener","severity":"INFO","message":"Initialized artemis-plugin plugin","threadName":"main","threadId":1,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"workhorse","processName":"Artemis","processId":1025544,"@version":"1","service_id":"eric-eo-cm-cust-wf","json-format":"true"}
{"log_timestamp":"2022-03-10T13:38:28.276-06:00","sequence":48,"loggerClassName":"org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLogger","loggerName":"io.hawt.HawtioContextListener","severity":"INFO","message":"Initialising hawtio services","threadName":"main","threadId":1,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"workhorse","processName":"Artemis","processId":1025544,"@version":"1","service_id":"eric-eo-cm-cust-wf","json-format":"true"}
{"log_timestamp":"2022-03-10T13:38:28.292-06:00","sequence":49,"loggerClassName":"org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLogger","loggerName":"io.hawt.system.ConfigManager","severity":"INFO","message":"Configuration will be discovered via system properties","threadName":"main","threadId":1,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"workhorse","processName":"Artemis","processId":1025544,"@version":"1","service_id":"eric-eo-cm-cust-wf","json-format":"true"}
{"log_timestamp":"2022-03-10T13:38:28.294-06:00","sequence":50,"loggerClassName":"org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLogger","loggerName":"io.hawt.jmx.JmxTreeWatcher","severity":"INFO","message":"Welcome to Hawtio 2.14.0","threadName":"main","threadId":1,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"workhorse","processName":"Artemis","processId":1025544,"@version":"1","service_id":"eric-eo-cm-cust-wf","json-format":"true"}
{"log_timestamp":"2022-03-10T13:38:28.298-06:00","sequence":51,"loggerClassName":"org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLogger","loggerName":"io.hawt.web.auth.AuthenticationConfiguration","severity":"INFO","message":"Starting hawtio authentication filter, JAAS realm: \"activemq\" authorized role(s): \"amq\" role principal classes: \"org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.RolePrincipal\"","threadName":"main","threadId":1,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"workhorse","processName":"Artemis","processId":1025544,"@version":"1","service_id":"eric-eo-cm-cust-wf","json-format":"true"}
{"log_timestamp":"2022-03-10T13:38:28.304-06:00","sequence":52,"loggerClassName":"org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLogger","loggerName":"io.hawt.web.auth.LoginRedirectFilter","severity":"INFO","message":"Hawtio loginRedirectFilter is using 1800 sec. HttpSession timeout","threadName":"main","threadId":1,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"workhorse","processName":"Artemis","processId":1025544,"@version":"1","service_id":"eric-eo-cm-cust-wf","json-format":"true"}
{"log_timestamp":"2022-03-10T13:38:28.315-06:00","sequence":53,"loggerClassName":"org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLogger","loggerName":"io.hawt.web.proxy.ProxyServlet","severity":"INFO","message":"Proxy servlet is disabled","threadName":"main","threadId":1,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"workhorse","processName":"Artemis","processId":1025544,"@version":"1","service_id":"eric-eo-cm-cust-wf","json-format":"true"}
{"log_timestamp":"2022-03-10T13:38:28.321-06:00","sequence":54,"loggerClassName":"org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLogger","loggerName":"io.hawt.web.servlets.JolokiaConfiguredAgentServlet","severity":"INFO","message":"Jolokia overridden property: [key=policyLocation, value=file:/home/jbertram/java/artemis/apache-artemis-2.20.0/bin/jsonLogging/etc/jolokia-access.xml]","threadName":"main","threadId":1,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"workhorse","processName":"Artemis","processId":1025544,"@version":"1","service_id":"eric-eo-cm-cust-wf","json-format":"true"}
{"log_timestamp":"2022-03-10T13:38:28.383-06:00","sequence":55,"loggerClassName":"java.util.logging.Logger","loggerName":"org.apache.activemq.artemis","severity":"INFO","message":"AMQ241001: HTTP Server started at http://localhost:8161","threadName":"main","threadId":1,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"workhorse","processName":"Artemis","processId":1025544,"@version":"1","service_id":"eric-eo-cm-cust-wf","json-format":"true"}
{"log_timestamp":"2022-03-10T13:38:28.383-06:00","sequence":57,"loggerClassName":"java.util.logging.Logger","loggerName":"org.apache.activemq.artemis","severity":"INFO","message":"AMQ241002: Artemis Jolokia REST API available at http://localhost:8161/console/jolokia","threadName":"main","threadId":1,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"workhorse","processName":"Artemis","processId":1025544,"@version":"1","service_id":"eric-eo-cm-cust-wf","json-format":"true"}
{"log_timestamp":"2022-03-10T13:38:28.383-06:00","sequence":59,"loggerClassName":"java.util.logging.Logger","loggerName":"org.apache.activemq.artemis","severity":"INFO","message":"AMQ241004: Artemis Console available at http://localhost:8161/console","threadName":"main","threadId":1,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"workhorse","processName":"Artemis","processId":1025544,"@version":"1","service_id":"eric-eo-cm-cust-wf","json-format":"true"}
^C{"log_timestamp":"2022-03-10T13:38:35.081-06:00","sequence":61,"loggerClassName":"org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLogger","loggerName":"io.hawt.web.auth.AuthenticationFilter","severity":"INFO","message":"Destroying hawtio authentication filter","threadName":"shutdown-hook","threadId":14,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"workhorse","processName":"Artemis","processId":1025544,"@version":"1","service_id":"eric-eo-cm-cust-wf","json-format":"true"}
{"log_timestamp":"2022-03-10T13:38:35.084-06:00","sequence":62,"loggerClassName":"org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLogger","loggerName":"io.hawt.HawtioContextListener","severity":"INFO","message":"Destroying hawtio services","threadName":"shutdown-hook","threadId":14,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"workhorse","processName":"Artemis","processId":1025544,"@version":"1","service_id":"eric-eo-cm-cust-wf","json-format":"true"}
{"log_timestamp":"2022-03-10T13:38:35.093-06:00","sequence":63,"loggerClassName":"org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLogger","loggerName":"org.apache.activemq.hawtio.plugin.PluginContextListener","severity":"INFO","message":"Destroyed artemis-plugin plugin","threadName":"shutdown-hook","threadId":14,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"workhorse","processName":"Artemis","processId":1025544,"@version":"1","service_id":"eric-eo-cm-cust-wf","json-format":"true"}
{"log_timestamp":"2022-03-10T13:38:35.096-06:00","sequence":64,"loggerClassName":"org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLogger","loggerName":"org.apache.activemq.hawtio.branding.PluginContextListener","severity":"INFO","message":"Destroyed activemq-branding plugin","threadName":"shutdown-hook","threadId":14,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"workhorse","processName":"Artemis","processId":1025544,"@version":"1","service_id":"eric-eo-cm-cust-wf","json-format":"true"}
{"log_timestamp":"2022-03-10T13:38:35.11-06:00","sequence":65,"loggerClassName":"java.util.logging.Logger","loggerName":"org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server","severity":"INFO","message":"AMQ221002: Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Message Broker version 2.20.0 [f41aef33-a07b-11ec-aa6f-5c80b6f32172] stopped, uptime 7.851 seconds","threadName":"shutdown-hook","threadId":14,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"workhorse","processName":"Artemis","processId":1025544,"@version":"1","service_id":"eric-eo-cm-cust-wf","json-format":"true"}
```

Comment: Hi Justin...can you show an extract from the bin/artemis with this added ... ?

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment. Hope that helps!

Comment: Ok Justin..my exec command is considerably shorter with far less - options - I do not have an existing -Xbootclasspath/a

Comment: Hi Justin ... I did the above and confirmed the jar file was added but still get the error

Comment: I created a fresh instance of ActiveMQ Artemis 2.20.0 and made the aforementioned changes and everything is working fine with your JSON-related updates in `logging.properties`.

Comment: Did you edit the artemis.sh after creating the broker instance ? I create the broker and then artemis run in the same script

Comment: I think you're looking at the `artemis` script from the home directory, not the instance directory. I updated my answer to make this more clear.

Comment: Is there some way to take a paramater into the instance artemis.sh ... I cannot edit the instance artemis.sh ? I will just copy it into the instance before running

Comment: The `bin/artemis` script doesn't support passing any parameters for specifying the Xbootclasspath. Why can't you edit the instance's `bin/artemis` script?

Comment: I copied the "edited" script in and it works - Thank you so much Justin